# Spring boot is appending special characters "()" in native mysql query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a native mysql query which takes in a list of string as an argument and returns list of string.
The query gets executed on Project A , but not in Project B since "()" is added in the query which results in Mysql Syntax exception

**ExampleController:**

```
    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/testQuery")
    public List<String> testQuery(@RequestParam List<String> ids){
        return exampleRepository.testQuery(ids);
    }
```

**ExampleRepository:**

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT id FROM example WHERE id IN ?1 ORDER BY FIELD(id , ?1) " ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> testQuery(List<String> ids);
```

**application.yml config:**

```
server:
  port: 50001
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
    path: /error

spring:
  main:
    allow-circular-references: true
  
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: <user>
    password: <password>
    
    hikari:
      auto-commit: true
      minimum-idle: 1
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      idle-timeout: 600000
      pool-name: SpringBootJPAHikariCP
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      connection-timeout: 30000

  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 100MB
      max-request-size: 100MB

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
```

The above files are same for both Project A and Project B,
as mentioned the only change is the pom.xml files

**Project-A's pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProjectA</name>
    <description>Project-A</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
    

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.322</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Project-B's pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProjectB</name>
    <description>Project-B</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.455</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.fastjson2</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Since we have jpa property show-sql: true in our yaml configuration file , the querie displayed in Project A and Project B are as follows,

Project A's console:

[image: Console-A]

Project B's console:

[image: Console-B]

Some library is causing the sql syntax exception error , Since I am migrating my project to use new libraries I cant use the old libraries sicne spring boots new version doesnt support certain libraries. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't run that query as native, it needs to be run as a JPA query.  And therefore you can't use the raw MySQL `FIELD()` when ordering, you will need to find some workaround.

Comment: I am able to run that query on Project A and its returning me proper result as well.